# Delete Collection View Cell from Collection View Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have an application in Xcode 4.6 with a collection view. I have added a delete button to each collection view cell to offer the user the option to delete the cell.

Although I realize that a collection view is similar to a table view (and I know how to delete cells from a table view), deleting objects seems to work differently in a collection view. I looked in the class reference for collection views, but being new to iOS, I am having trouble applying their suggested code to my project.  The documentation shows the following suggested code for deleting cells:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
NSArray* itemPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

// Delete the items from the data source.
[self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:itemPaths];

// Now delete the items from the collection view.
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:tempArray];
}   completion:nil];
```

So I added this code inside my button action method. And where it says "temp array", I substituted the array that the collection view is using as its data source to determine the number of cells to display.  But I am confused as to what "deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:" is. Is this a delegate method? The compiler warns that it is not declared. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears to be a utility method to remove the given NSIndexPaths from a data source array.  That's not so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And where it says "temp array", I substituted the array that the collection view is using as its data source to determine the number of cells to display.

That's your first problem: the array, more than likely, does not contain instances of NSIndexPath, which is what that method expects.  What you probably want is to pass in the `itemPaths` array, which would make the collection view remove literally the "index paths of all selected rows."

> "deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:" is. Is this a delegate method?

Nope, that's pseudo-code.  Apple didn't see it necessary to digress into a discussion on how to remove objects from an array in a loop, and neither do I.  You have to implement that method yourself, or hope that NSIndexPath doesn't act up, and use `-removeObjectsInArray:` to update your data source properly.

Answer (score 0):

[Clear sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080322/remove-an-item-from-a-uicollectionview) is available here. Delete from the datasource first and then delete those indexPaths from the view. 2 step operation and should be done in the same sequence.